# How to add meta tags from a separate file

Tags: php, html, include, meta

How can I add my meta tags from another file?
If I want to include the tags with the function "include_once" it includes the meta tags into the body content.

Thanks for your replying!

Comment: Not much to go on here. The include_once function will include the specified file wherever you place it in the document. Can you post the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could do this with `require_once()`. hope it helps.

meta.php

```
<?php

    $meta = "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php require_once('meta.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
     <?php echo $meta; ?>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I also add stylesheets like this?

Comment: I think it's possible.

Comment: Thank You very much! In the index file I just wrote the require function without the echo. In the meta file I just list the meta tags without any php code...

Comment: no worries - from here you could construct an entirely dynamic `<head>` for your document. just add more variables to the meta.php.

Comment: My problem was that I added the require function in the head section. If You add the function before the html section, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this.

**meta.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include_once ('meta.php');?>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've included the meta tags like your example but as I've written, it shows me the meta tags into the body section

Comment: php opening and closing brackets should be added on the meta.php in order to not dispay the tags into the body.